# Should I open an url in WebView inside app or in browser?

Tags: android, webview

I was wondering if there is a best practice in Android about WebView/Browsers. I want to open an url in my app to show a web page but I do not have anything to retrieve from that page so I do not need to show it in a webview inside my app. Should I show that page in a browser or in a webview ?

Comment: Its depend on you ! If you load url in web view then may be some memory leak issue create. So instead of it open in browser.

Comment: It totally depends on you and on your requirements

Comment: So there is no best practice in that case ?

Comment: No. Not like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you should open an URL in `WebView` or `Browser` that totally depends upon your requirements. Still I am adding some points that you can consider:

**Browser:**

- If you have some data like *Privacy Policy* of your organization, that just for user information. You do not require any inputs from user.

**WebView:**

If you want to,

- Customize content of URL
- Get some input from User
- Send some information to Server

Thank You!

Comment: Thank for your answer it consolidate what I was thinking !

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer:**

From your context, it looks going the Browser way is good enough.

**Details:**

When you don't have user inputs to process and it is not part of the user-flow in your app, go about showing it in the Browser. It's easier that way, because you don't have to manage anything explicitly.

When you have something to process or that this window is some part of your in-app flow, you should go the WebView way. It gives you the power to manage things and you really need to code of situations like user pressing "back button", and the like. I mean, you're the owner of the life-cycle management of the WebView and see how it seamlessly fits in your user flow while (s)he is at it.

Comment: Thank for your answer it consolidate what I was thinking !